# If condition is working correctly by my else condition is not working with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the information from a LinkedIn page

Here's the code for that :

```
likes_bs4tags = soup.find_all("span", attrs = {"class" : "social-details-social-counts__social-proof-fallback-number"})
if likes_bs4tags:
    for tag in likes_bs4tags:
        strtag = str(tag)
        list_of_matches = re.findall('[,0-9]+',strtag)
        last_string = list_of_matches.pop()
        without_comma = last_string.replace(',','')
        likes_int = int(without_comma)
        likes.append(likes_int)
else:
    likes_bs4tags_ = soup.find_all("span", attrs = {"class" : "social-details-social-counts__reactions-count"})
    for i in likes_bs4tags_:
        strtag_ = str(i)
        list_of_matches = re.findall('[,0-9]+',strtag_)
        last_string = list_of_matches.pop()
        without_comma = last_string.replace(',','')
        likes_int = int(without_comma)
        likes.append(likes_int)
```

Here my if condition is working correctly and returning me the information I want but my else condition isn't working.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: We are going to need a bit more information.
what is not working, is the else clause never triggered? does the second .find_all not find anything? do you get a errormessage?

Comment: Not related to your question but you can write the class as a keyword argument by `class_`: [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)

Comment: @BendikKnapstad Yes the else clause never triggered and the second.find_all condition is not returning anything not even the errormessage.

Comment: Do you mean when your `if` condition is `False`, the `else` condition does not work?

Comment: @AjeetVerma Yes

Comment: @DarkKnight No he meant that instead of using attrs = class in the soup.find_all statement i could've used class_

Comment: what's the output of `likes_bs4tags` in both cases when it finds element and when it can not. I think you should better define the `if` condition

Comment: @AjeetVerma So basically I'm trying to scrape the total number of likes on LinkedIn posts, the thing is that it is returning me the likes from all the posts having class used in the if condition but it is skipping the posts with the class used in the else condition, basically it's just skipping the else condition

Comment: You should probably have two if conditions instead of the else. If it finds a list in the if clause its never going to run the else

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid code repetition by looping over the two possible classes. If you run find_all for a class that reveals something, you can process that data then break. Something like this:

```
for class_ in "social-details-social-counts__social-proof-fallback-number", "social-details-social-counts__reactions-count":
    if likes_bs4tags := soup.find_all("span", class_=class_):
        print('processing:', _class)
        for tag in likes_bs4tags:
            strtag = str(tag)
            list_of_matches = re.findall('[,0-9]+',strtag)
            last_string = list_of_matches.pop()
            without_comma = last_string.replace(',','')
            likes_int = int(without_comma)
            likes.append(likes_int)
        break
else:
    print('Nothing found')
```